# Convert monetary string to array and total

Tags: c#, arrays, sum

I'm using c#, I have a string of cash entries I need to add together and get the total

`arrTotalSplitCosts.Text = "24.90,10.60,1.90,20";`

While the below works, as soon as I add a decimal point or a string value to replace the numbers in the array with my generated numbers, the below crashes

```
int[] arr = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
{
 sum += arr[i];
}
```

I want to take these values from a form post:

`arrTotalSplitCosts.Text = "24.90,10.60,1.90,20";`

And total them e.g. Total = 57.40

Anyone got any ideas, I'm struggling, thanks in advance.

Comment: What error do you receive?

Comment: `arrTotalSplitCosts.Text.Split(',').Select(decimal.Parse).Sum()` however if someone adds anything that cant be parsed as a decimal, kaboom! for which you might want to use TryParse and filter the results. or validate and alert the user

Comment: Thanks for the -1 vote, apologies for my lack of understanding, Thanks to people like Jonathan and Mustafa for their help in making this a great forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input is a `string` (not an array of `string`, but a single `string`).

You then have to take that `string` and split it into a list or array.

The values have decimals, so they cannot be dealt with as `int`. `int` is an integer; a whole number. You should deal with your data as a list of `double`s.

When you convert from `string` to `double`, you should use `tryparse`, as you can more stringently enforce the conversion and check for exceptions as you go.

I've put a sample below, but note that I made it much more verbose than I normally would, just to (hopefully) more clearly show each of the steps.

If I was going to actually do this, I would use Linq more and combine multiple steps into single lines.

So something like this:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
                        
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
            var inString = "24.90,10.60,1.90,20";
            
            var stringValues = inString.Split(',');
            List<double> doubleValues = new List<double>();
            
            foreach(string v in stringValues){
                double outNum;
                double num = double.TryParse(v, out outNum)? outNum : 0;
                doubleValues.Add(num);
            }
            
            Console.WriteLine(doubleValues.Sum(i => i)); // output = 57.4
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks you so much Jonathan, I did not know about double and tryparse, this is amazing. Can't thank you enough. Have a great day.

Comment: No problem. If this is your accepted answer, you should mark it as such.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `,` as a seperator. You can prefer `;`.

For 10.000,00 formatting style

```
var sum = arrTotalSplitCosts.Text.Split(';').Select(decimal.Parse).Sum()
```

For 10,000.00 formatting style

```
var sum = arrTotalSplitCosts.Split(';').Select(a => decimal.Parse(a, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)).Sum()
```

Comment: Thanks Mustafa, I never gave that a thought, great idea, thankfully Jonathan's explanation was a great approach and did the job, have a great day, again thanks for your time.